# joining two table with multiple condtions

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have two tables   and selected month april  and session is 1

**studentprofile**

```
sud_id   name        session_id

1         kp            1

2         kishan        1

3          raj          1
4          arti         1        not any fee submitted till now
5          kp           2        session is diffrent
```

**fee_generate**

```
fee_id    stud_id    fee_balance  delay    name     session_id   feemonth 

1            1         0            0       kp         1         april

2            2         10           10     kishan      1         april
3            2         0            0      kishan      1         april      he cleared his balance

4            3         0            0      raj        1          march      fee not submitted in this month

5            5         0            0      kp         1          april       here session is diffrent...  so nothing to do with this session
```

I want to show those students whose fee is not submitted OR have any balance OR any Delay, till selected month(in this case let april), with session 1 which means that I want to show is as follows:

```
arti and raj
```

**My Current query:**

```
select s.* from studentprofile s 
            left join 
            fee_generate f 
            on 
            s.stud_id=f.stud_id 
            where  

            s.session_id='$session_id'  and s.stud_class='$class' 
            and 
            (  f.stud_id is null or  ( f.feemonth='$selected_fee_month1' and (f.delay>0.00 or f.fee_balance>0.00)))
                   order by s.name desc
```

I am not able to write the query with any `join`. My second problem is that name columns are common in both tables. So the selected name column should come from `studentprofile` table and order by name according to `studentprofile` table.

Comment: Hi Krishanpal, welcome to Stackoverflow! Questions need to have a [clear problem statement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you provide a code sample, someone may be able to help you with this. The [Asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is worth a read too.

Comment: Your studentprofile table has no column stud_class but you use it in your query. You should correct it so it is easier to fiddle your question.

Answer (score 0):

try to make a left outer joing, in your where you can check if the fee_id IS NULL (no record) OR delay/fee_balance is bigger than 0.
like this

```
SELECT
    s.*
FROM studentprofile s
LEFT OUTER JOIN fee_generate fg
    ON fg.stud_id = s.sud_id
    AND fg.feemonth='$selected_fee_month1'
WHERE 
    s.session_id='$session_id'
    AND s.stud_class='$class' 
    AND (fg.fee_id IS NULL
        OR fg.delay > 0
        OR fg.fee_balance > 0)
```

Code not tested

Tip: your feemonth field does not contain a year information, i think it will be a good idea to create a feeyear field too.